# Humorous word for the situation when people know your thoughts

Tags: single-word-requests

The question is at least 4 minutes long.

**Statutory Warning:** The link leads to a Facebook page.

I saw [this video](https://www.facebook.com/comedycentralindia/videos/973653642653481/) recently. What is the word to describe the situation in which the girl has fallen into at the end of the video? Looking for a comic word.

---

If you don't want to or cannot see a link on Facebook, here's the question for you:

What is the word to describe the *situation* you have fallen into when all (or at least all the important) people around you have become aware of the wicked (not evil) things you say or think about them? You aren't a gossipmonger or a backbiter. You are a good person and the situation is humorous. Kind of like your boss was behind you when you were mimicking him/her.

Comment: **Warning**: tvtropes; [Right Behind Me](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RightBehindMe)?

Comment: She really ***put her foot in it***

Comment: The mask slipped?

Comment: "She sticked her foot in her mouth" what means *to say something that you regret; to say something stupid, insulting, or hurtful*.

Comment: @deadrat: *The mask slipped* is more of a serious phrase than a comic one. No? In particular, my neuro association with masks is [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=nY4tDDO93E8C&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36).

Comment: @displayName You're right.  Inapt for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain how relevant this is as I am not able to view the video, but a common recent idiom for the situation you described is "Busted!" or "You are so busted!", meaning "Your indiscretions have been found out".

Sadly I cannot find any citations that express this specific meaning, but I hope it is recognisable slang from recent popular culture.

Comment: Busted is how a second person would describe the firs person's state. How would the first person describe this state herself?

Comment: @displayName "I am soooo busted!" springs easily to mind...

Answer (score 2):

You could say, *she is **caught with her pants down***.

> caught with pants down: caught in a situation that embarrasses you [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/caught+with+pants+down)

Or

*She is caught in her **true colors***.

> someone's true colors: someone's true attitude, opinions, or biases.
>   [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/true+colors)

Answer (score 2):

Caught in the act.

Though that's more used when it comes to sexual relationships.

Comment: I wouldn't say so.  The phrase is widely used for a wide variety of non sexual misdemeanours.

Comment: "She was caught in the act." is how somebody would tell about her. Do you have any thought about how would she herself describe her situation? Looking for single-word in the sentence spoken with a sheepish grin- "I was *caught in the act.*".

Answer (score 1):

The word [**"awkward"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awkward) is used in this situation, but it has to be said with a certain inflection and a short pause for the full, "comically" embarrassing effect. Something like **"Aaawwk-ward..."**

> ​causing ​problems, ​worry, or ​embarrassment:
>   *an awkward ​position/​situation*
>    (-- Merriam-Webster)